# trouble setting javascript variable to output of php

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to set a javascript variable to the output of a php script but the JS variable continues to evaluate to the literal output of the PHP snippet.

Even when I do something as simple as this in my .js file:

```
var list = "<?php echo 'foo'?>";
```

the JS variable comes out as:

```
"<?php echo 'foo'?>"
```

When I try removing the quotes, I get parsing errors.

I've seen several examples like the above on various sites, though, so it seems like this should work.

Comment: Have you tried to rename your .js file to .php?

Comment: If it's in your `.js` file, then it's not in your `.php` file...? You can only use PHP syntax in PHP

Comment: That was the trick.  Moving is to the <script> section of my .php file worked!  Thank you!

Comment: a word of caution: passing variables like that is against best practice for good reasons.  If you can make a php endpoint return json data and use ajax to fetch it, that would be the best way to pass information from the back end to the front end.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. In the end I wound up doing what you described. Took me a while to get there though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments above pointed out, the solution was to run that snippet of Javascript in a .php file.

I just moved that line to the

```
<script>
```

section of my main .php file, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

In order for those php tags to run, they need to be in a file that actually executes php (so a .php file). Putting that line in a script tag at the top of the head in a php file will solve your problem. (Side-note: If you prefer to use html files instead like I do, you can add `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html` to your `.htaccess` file in your root directory. This will make php execute html files as well.)

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var list = "<?php echo 'foo'?>";
    </script>
    ...
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```